# Carregamento muito lento (Angular 4)

Tags: angular

Coloquei uma aplicação em Angular 4.3 em produção e percebo que o primeiro carregamento é bastante lento para o tamanho da aplicação (2.93 mb)

O site não faz conexão com API Rest no momento, é somente a parte visual.

Dei uma olhada na ferramenta de desenvolvimento do Chrome e percebi que o arquivo que mais demora a carregar é o **vendor**.
Percebi também que ele não está conseguindo ler fontes com extensão .woff2.

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que está ocasionando isso e como resolver?

link: https://www.tecnologiainfo.com.br/sgba/

Comment: aqui abriu normal, qual o tempo do vendor pra vc, aqui deu 118ms

Comment: Aqui foi 9.3s. A internet aparentemente está com boa velocidade. Estranho!

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia Duilio, como você está gerando suas versões em produção.

Está utilizando `ng build --prod` ??

Se não o problema por ser este.

Se sim, como sua aplicação foi construída? Você está usando o conceito "lazy loading" ?? Se não de uma olhada neste vídeo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=glOJxHDkdnQ&t=492s.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Bom dia Eduardo, obrigado pela resposta!
Utilizei o ng build --prod sim!
Ainda não apliquei o Lazt loading, mesmo porque existem poucos componentes sendo carregados. De mais relevante somente os componentes do PrimeNg.
Você testou o carregamento ai? Demorou muito?
Contudo ainda acho estranho demorar quase 10s para carregar um arquivo de 2.93mb. De qualquer maneira vou aplicar o lazy loading pra ver se melhora significativamente.

Comment: Duilio, eu utilizo o lazy loading em meu projeto, da uma diferença bem grande.

Answer (score 1):

O problema principal era que estava carregando módulos desnecessariamente, principalmente os oriundos ao PrimeNg. Corrigi as importações e ativei a compactação Gzip no servidor, melhorou consideravelmente.

Vou adicionar a estratégia do Lazy Loading também e deve melhorar ainda mais.

Agradeço a ajuda de vocês!